# Kivy + Python + Camera = Does not work on Android

Tags: android, python, camera, kivy

apk-app does not work on android.
Try to work with the camera via Python + Kivy on Android. But the application terminates. What could be the problem?
The application runs on MakOS.
The app does not work on Android

Details:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        cam=Camera(index=0,resolution=(640,480), size=(500,500))
        return cam

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

adb logcat *:W

```
W/ResourceType(21004): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020203
W/ResourceType(21004): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020203
W/ResourceType(21004): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020203
W/ResourceType(21004): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020203
W/AudioDigitalControl(  134): GetAfeDigitalStatus mAudioMEMIF[9] state = 1, mAudioDigitalBlock = 1
W/AudioPlatformDevice(  134): GetULFrequency with frequency = 44100
W/AudioPlatformDevice(  134): GetULFrequency with frequency = 44100
W/ResourceType(21004): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020203
W/asset   (  572): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
W/ActivityManager(  572): [LTK] pid, app, 3d=21004, 7163904, 160800768
W/ActivityManager(  572): Unable to write /sys/module/mlog/parameters/do_mlog
E/Trace   ( 1336): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/        ( 3961): appName=com.android.systemui, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
E/        ( 3961): 0
E/        ( 3961): appName=com.android.systemui, acAppName=com.android.browser
E/        ( 3961): 0
W/SurfaceFlinger(  130): GraphicBuffer(0x417654d0) is rejected
W/SurfaceFlinger(  130): [Layer::activeBufferBackup] mActiveBuffer=0x0 not initialized
W/MediatekClassFactory(  572): OP not exist!, Get obj from default class
W/MediatekClassFactory(  572): Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
E/AudioService(  572): handleConfigurationChanged() createInstance IAudioServiceExt fail
W/asset   ( 1336): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
W/ResourceType( 1336): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
W/ResourceType( 1336): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
E/linker  ( 1336): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
E/dalvikvm( 1336): dlopen("/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
E/linker  ( 1336): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
E/dalvikvm( 1336): dlopen("/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "/data/data/org.test.testcam/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
E/linker  ( 1336): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
E/        ( 1336): appName=org.test.testcam:python, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
E/        ( 1336): 0
E/        ( 1336): appName=org.test.testcam:python, acAppName=com.android.browser
E/        ( 1336): 0
E/        ( 1336): appName=org.test.testcam:python, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
E/        ( 1336): 0
E/        ( 1336): appName=org.test.testcam:python, acAppName=com.android.browser
E/        ( 1336): 0
W/SDLSurface( 1336): Create egl surface
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21004): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/ActivityManager(  572): Unable to write /sys/module/mlog/parameters/do_mlog
```

buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Test Camera

# (str) Package name
package.name = testcam

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 1.2.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,mechanize

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = CAMERA    

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: `library "libmaliinstr.so" not found` ,`.._imaging.so" not found`,`_sqlite3.so" not found`

Comment: You'd probably get a   better response on this trying to ask diectly to the people involved in the Kivy project - http://kivy.org/#support

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should crash, but the Camera widget doesn't work on android because it's not easy to access the camera stream like on desktop.

You can use the [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) method if you just want to get an image.